# How to install and update specific Ubuntu kernel version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I have a 22.04 LTS Ubuntu server with 5.15.0-60-generic kernel version. I want to update my kernel version to 5.19.0-38 using CLI. Most of the people online use mainline repository for their usage. But There is no version i'm looking for in [mainline](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) repository.

As far as i know, the mainline repository is only for debugging purpose, not for production purpose.

How can i download specific kernel version i wrote above to my server? what is the official Ubuntu kernel repository that has all of Ubuntu kernel versions? And what's the difference between mainline repository and [canonical team repository](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)?

Installing specific kernel version(not only latest kernel version) is important to me because as a engineer, sometimes i have to change the kernel version of new nodes to the same version as existing node in cluster for ease of management.

Comment: There is no interest to upgrade from an LTS version to an EOL (end of life) non-LTS version. You should target to upgrade (somehow) to 6.1.x (LTS) or 6.4.x (current stable). If you're asking precisely 5.19 (btw: 5.19.0.38 doesn't make much sense either there was 5.19.17, not 5.19.38, but what does 5.19.0.38 mean? on what distribution?) that probably means you need it for a proprietary driver, but this should be explained in the question.

Comment: Sorry, i made a typo. i meant 5.19.0-38 version Ubuntu kernel.